# Can't integrate Google Maps to my ionic 2 App

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to put google maps in to my app.

added the GMaps plugin.

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="my android api" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="my ios api"
```

added necessary dependencies.

```
npm install
```

However, when I try to run the app I get this runtime error.

> ```
> **Runtime Error**
> Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
> **Stack**
> Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
>     at s (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4211)
>     at s (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4034)
>     at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4574
>     at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9723)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:35879:37)
>     at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9659)
>     at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7083)
>     at i (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3671)
>     at HTMLAnchorElement.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10876)
> ```

Here is the typescript code:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapsLatLng,
  GoogleMapsMarker,
  Geolocation
} from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
  private _latitude: number;
  private _longitude: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let map = new GoogleMap(document.getElementById('map'));

    // when the map is ready
    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
        this._latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
        this._longitude = pos.coords.longitude;

        // move the camera
        map.moveCamera({
          target: new GoogleMapsLatLng(this._latitude, this._longitude),
          zoom: 18,
          tilt: 30
        }).then(() => {

          // add a marker
          map.addMarker({
            position: new GoogleMapsLatLng(this._latitude, this._longitude),
            title: 'You are here!'
          })

            // show marker info
          .then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
            marker.showInfoWindow();

            // listen to all available events
            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MAP_CLICK');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_LONG_CLICK).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MAP_LONG_CLICK');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MY_LOCATION_CHANGE).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MY_LOCATION_CHANGE');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MY_LOCATION_BUTTON_CLICK).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MY_LOCATION_BUTTON_CLICK');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.INDOOR_BUILDING_FOCUSED).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('INDOOR_BUILDING_FOCUSED');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.INDOOR_LEVEL_ACTIVATED).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('INDOOR_LEVEL_ACTIVATED');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.CAMERA_CHANGE).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('CAMERA_CHANGE');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.CAMERA_IDLE).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('CAMERA_IDLE');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MAP_READY');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_LOADED).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MAP_LOADED');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_WILL_MOVE).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MAP_WILL_MOVE');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLOSE).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MAP_CLOSE');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MARKER_CLICK');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.OVERLAY_CLICK).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('OVERLAY_CLICK');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.INFO_CLICK).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('INFO_CLICK');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MARKER_DRAG');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_START).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MARKER_DRAG_START');
              });

            map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_DRAG_END).subscribe(
              () => {
                alert('MARKER_DRAG_END');
              });

          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Couldn't find where the problem is, seems like a dependency or a plugin issue.

Comment: I've found a tutorial about [Ionic 2: How to Use Google Maps & Geolocation](https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/), this provides a basic integration of Ionic App and Google Maps SDK. For a more advanced implementation of Google Maps in Ionic 2, check out [this tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-advanced-google-maps-component-in-ionic-2/). Just follow the tutorial to be familiarize with the code implementation on the integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to build first or run app on an emulator as the google map SDK for ionic does not run on browser.

either run app on emulator using `ionic run android` or
Build app `ionic build android`

Comment: This may be another solution but Instead I used Google Maps Javascript API